# Make the selected tab active and remaining inactive using pure javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

Am having the dynamic tabs there might me 'n' number of tabs am able to capture the tab when its clicked and change its background color to green.
But when I select the other tab the tab which is clicked previously also remains in green but inactive tabs should be in white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unset background of all the tabs first and then add the background color to the selected tab like this:

```
 function showActiveTab(item)
  {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");

    // Unset background color of all tabs to white
    for (var i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {
      el[i].style.background="white";
    }
    // Add background color of selected tab to green
    item.style.background="green";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Track which tab is active like this and just set the background to white (or whatever you like) when it changes.

```
var activeTab = null;
function showActiveTab(item)
{
    if (null != activeTab) {
        activeTab.style.background="white";
    }
    item.style.background="green";
    activeTab = item;
}
```

Small change to clickTabEvent to remove the anonymous method call that you were using to work around the local `item` being referenced in the all the on-click handlers

```
function clickTabEvent()
{
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {
        var item = el[i];
        if (item.id && (item.id.indexOf("tab_")!=-1)) {
            item.addEventListener('click',
                function() {
                    showTabPanel(this);
                    showActiveTab(this);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```